# If we had access to magnetic monopoles, what types of “electromagnetronics” might that enable?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, magnetic-monopoles

This is a very broad question, but answers that give any sort of insight are welcome.

As we know, the electronics revolution of the 20th century was based on a variety of interesting electrodynamical effects, studied and reviewed (now) in device physics, that lead to the development of semiconductor-based transistors and computers. More recently, healthy research has been done into spintronics, which rely on the inherent magnetic properties of electrons.

However, those properties are based on dipole, and higher order, magnetic effects, hence the term spintronics. This leads me to wonder:

**What are a few conjectures of technologies we might enable if we had access to magnetic charges (monopoles) that we could integrate with our electronics?**

I will upvote answers that point to relevant literature or help me to develop my intuition. A discussion of relevant device physics is welcome.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67448

Comment: @Nihar Karve thanks for the link. At the level of skimming, the only interesting thing there for me was the top answer, although it was particular to a single thought experiment. I'd like to see more general elaborations with a greater focus on technology.